# c++11 - random device usage

Tags: c++11, random

What is the different between

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 100);
for (int n = 0; n < 100; ++n)
    std::cout<<dist(gen)<<std::endl;
```

and

```
std::random_device rd;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 100);
for (int n = 0; n < 100; ++n)
    std::cout<<dist(rd)<<std::endl;
```

The first example use rd() as a seed, but the output is similar, I want know what's the advantage of first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is that in the first example you specifically set the [mersenne-twister](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937/?kw=mt19937) as the random-number generator. The mersenne-twister is a pseudo-random generator and is seeded with a value from std::random_device. The mersenne-twister is considered a really good pseudo-random generator and will produce large volumes of high quality pseudo-random values quickly.

The [std::random_device](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/random_device/) is a "true" random-number generator in that it uses different stochastic processes to generate numbers that in practice are random. As such, I believe it isn't suitable if you need lots of random numbers very fast because it depends on these stochastic events happening (think user input, the noise in ad-measurements etc) for it to create a random state.

Comment: The performance I tested on windows vc11 release model are same. May be it depends on the implementation of random device. I agree mt19937 have better quality

Comment: The question of quality is not that simple. A true random-number generator should produce better random numbers, but as soon as you ask it to produce many random numbers, it will not be able to "consume" enough random events from the computer system to actually produce true random numbers.

Comment: But yes, you are right, the implementation can differ a lot.